# Confusion matrix subset of classes not working properly

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

[image][image]I have searched for an answer to this question on the internet including suggestion when writing the title but still to no avail so hopefully someone can help!

I am trying to construct a confusion matrix using sci-kit learn. This comes after a keras model.

This is bizarre because i am having the following problem: For the training and test set of the original data... I can construct the confusion matrix as follows (please note this is a multi-label problem and so data has to be subset for the different labels.

The following works fine:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_train[:,0:6].argmax(axis=1), trainpred[:,0:6].argmax(axis=1))
```

and the 6:18 etc... until all classes have been subset. The confusion matrix that forms as a result reflects the true outcome of the keras model..

The problem arises when i deploy the model on completely unseen data.

I deploy the model by calling `model.predict()` and get results as above. However, now I cannot subset confusion matrices in the same way.

The code cm=confusion_matrix etc...causes the output of the CM to be the wrong dimensions, even when specifying 0:6 etc..

I therefore used the code from above used but with the labels argument modification:

```
age[0,1,2,3,4]
organ[5,6,7,8]

cm = confusion_matrix(y_train[:,0:6].argmax(axis=1), trainpred[:,0:6].argmax(axis=1), labels=age)
```

The FIRST label (1:5) works perfectly... However, the next labels do not! I dont get the right values in the confusion matrices and the matching is also incorrect for those that are in there.

To put this in to context: there are over 400 samples in the unseen test data.

model.predict shows very high classification and correct scores for most labels..

calling CM=ytest[:,4:8]etc, does indeed produce a 4x4 matrix, however there are like 5 values in there not 400, and those values that are in there are not correctly matching.

Also.. with the labels age being 012345, subsetting the ytest to 0:6 causes the correct confusion matrix to form (i am unsure as to why the 6 has to be included in the subset... nevertheless i have tried different combinations with the same issue!

I have searched high and low for this answer so would really appreciate some assistance as it is incredibly frustrating. any more code/information i can provide i will be happy to!!

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `sub set confusion matrix`? Generally you generate a confusion matrix for all the data [NXN] for N classes, by using the prediction and actual labels. Could you attach an image of your expected output and some sample data?

Comment: Thank you! Yes please see attached to original question the added screenshots... to your question: my data is a multi-label classification. So I made ma mistake by saying subsetting confusion matrix.. rather it is subset the one-hot labels and the model.predict table in order to view individually a CM for each label. 0:6 is age, 6:18 is organ etc.... screenshot shows the first subsetting works for age, but that there are barely any labels in the organ CM.. it seems completely wrong (and does not reflect the prediction scores either)....

Comment: sorry just to add: the screenshot with 192 samples in 5x5 position is a great prediction as all samples are the same age... as you can see when I try and subset the data to show the second label (organ) subsetting as shown in the original post to show the next label produces the second screenshot.. a weird CM with none of the samples actually present in the matrix! As you can see from the first CM there are over 200 samples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to subset the generated confusion matrix, but you actually have to generate a new confusion matrix manually with the specified class labels. If you classes `A, B, C` you will get a 3X3 matrix. If you want to create matrix focusing only on class `A`, the other classes will become the `false` class, but the `false positive` and `false negative` will change and hence you cannot just sample the initial matrix.

This is how you show actually do it

```py
import matplotlib.pytplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def generate_matrix(y_true, predict, class_name):
    TP, FP, FN, TN = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if y_true[i] == class_name:
            if y_true[i] == predict[i]:
                TP += 1
            else:
                FN += 1
        else:
            if y_true[i] == predict[i]:
                TN += 1
            else:
                FP += 1
    return np.array([[TP, FP],
                     [FN, TN]])

# Plot new matrix
matrix = generate_matrix(actual_labels, 
                         predicted_labels, 
                         class_name = 'A')
```

This will generate a confusion matrix for `class A`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Most of the function makes peerfect sense! does for i in range(len(y_true)): allow for the label to be any length? for example, age is 6 classes, organ is 12: I am getting an error when running the following for the function:  matrix = generate_matrix(NormcountsOneHot1,SingleCelltestpred,class_name = OrganSC)
OrganSC is organSC=[6,7,8,9.. up to 17]..  I am getting a following error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: This function won't handle the encoding, you will have to add that. Currently it will accept a list of actual labels (`y_true`) and predicted labels (`predict`) and generate a confusion matrix for the `class_name`. Make sure you are feeding only a 1D list of labels.

Comment: Yep got it!! works perfectly! thank you so much again! will also play around to add one-hot in to the function also. thanks for all your help!